# Stuck Accessing elements in nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```
  Meteor.robot.find({}, { _id: 1 }).forEach(function (robot) { x.push(robot.emails) })
```

That will display :

```
 [ { address: 'robot1@rob.fr', working: false } ],
I20180725-16:58:32.924(2)?   [ { address: 'rob2@rob.com', working: true } ],
I20180725-16:58:32.924(2)?   [ { address: 'ROB4@rob.fr', working: false } ],
I20180725-16:58:32.924(2)?   [ { address: 'rob5@rob.com', working: false } ]
 ]
```

humans.json

```
    {
        "_id": "22YAE7bEXdST9MyrZ",
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2016-11-22T15:09:25.968Z"
        },
        "abilities": {
            "power": {
            "mana":78,
            "chakra":0
            "energy":60
}
        },
        "emails": [
            {
                "address": "Rob6@rob.com",
                "working": false
            }
        ],
        "roles": [
           "killing":true
]
    }
```

I want only to get the address that start with Uppercase and,  not the address  + working attribute. Like this.

```
['ROB4@rob.fr']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
Meteor.robot.find({''}, { _id: 1 }).forEach(function (robot) { 
if(robot.emails){
    for(var i = 0; i<robot.emails.length; i++){
       var email = robot.emails[i];
       var emailAddress = email.address;
       if(emailAddress && emailAddress.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && emailAddress.charCodeAt(0) <= 90){
             // pushing only when email address starts with Uppercase.
             x.push(email.address);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
******************************************************************************
(node:14178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Comment: That's returning me an array of undefined

Comment: i can't access the the robot.emails.address please check my question and see my result when i'm doing the initial function

Comment: ```Meteor.robot.find({''}, { _id: 1 }).forEach(function (robot) {
 forEach(robot.emails ,function(email) {
  x.push(email.address);
 });
);```

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta you can't access `robot.emails.address` since `robot.emails` is an array.

Comment: @FatalMerlin altered it.

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta that's returning   ReferenceError: forEach is not defined

Comment: @SarahJP my bad, modified the original answer, please check.

Comment: YESS THAT'S IT, i have just another question is there a way to only get the email that start with an UPPERCASE ?

Comment: @SarahJP Great. Mark this the correct answer please. For checking, if the email address starts with capital case, you can use this condition. 
`
if(email.address){
   if(email.address.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && email.address.charCodeAt(0) <= 90){ 
 // Email address's 1st character is upper case ,do what you want
} 
else {
   // Not upper case. 
}
}`

Comment: Sushim could you please edit the answer so i get only emails that start with Uppercase ?Thank you siir

Comment: @SarahJP done, altered original answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply get the address, just access the address property in emails through looping.

```
Meteor.robot.find({}, { _id: 1 }).forEach(function (robot) {
    var addresses = [];
    robot.emails.forEach(function(element) {
        if (typeof element.address != undefined) {
            addresses[] = element;
        }
    });
    x.push(addresses);
})
```

Comment: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
******************************************************************************
(node:14178) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Comment: is this an error after you use my code. try to use `console.log(robot.emails)` to get the result

Comment: Yes sir i think i have some value of address undefined that's why it's throwing this error

Comment: @david `robot.emails.address` is not accessible, as `robot.emails` is array.

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta so there's no way to get what i'm trying to achieve ?

Answer (score -1):

So since `robot.emails` is an array, the simple solution would be to iterate over the `emails` array and only return the address, not the `working` attribute.

To achieve this, you could for example use `.map`:

```
Meteor.robot.find({''}, {
    _id: 1
}).forEach(function (robot) {
    // only returns the address part of the robot object
    x.push(robot.emails.map(email => { return { address: email.address }; }))
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this returning me (node:16391) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: forEach is not defined

Comment: @SarahJP that shouldn't have anything todo with my code, since the `forEach` originates in you code example. "I have this function... `Meteor.robot.find({}, { _id: 1 }).forEach(function (robot) { x.push(robot.emails) })`"

Comment: @SarahJP could you maybe add more code so we can help identify this issue? You posted the same error for multiple answers, where it shouldn't be a problem in the answer's code

Comment: I see I get downvoted, please consider telling me why and how to improve? :)

Comment: It's not me sir i can't downvote and i wont downvote a person who's trying to help

Comment: @SarahJP can you try again? I incorporated the update that Sushim Mukul Dutta used